# Less oil on certain valves than others

Tags: noise, oil, valve, mustang, valve-lifter

I've got a 1986 3.8l 6-cylinder mustang. I've been hearing a ticking underneath the driver's side valve cover, so I took it off. I didn't see anything wrong so I started the engine sans valve cover. [This](https://youtu.be/HvWZJ9S38T0) is what it looks like.

Oil doesn't appear to be flowing up to the top of the two middle valves. I'm assuming those valves are the ones that are ticking as well. What would cause this?

Comment: In the old days ticking in the valve train was caused by stuck hydraulic lifters . Removing  them and cleaning varnish would usually fix them. ( Engines with rocker arms and the cam in the block.)

Comment: I agree with @blacksmith37, however, before you tear it apart to clean up lifters, you might try unsticking them through the use of some kind of engine cleaner. There's plenty on the market. Might save a lot of hassle.

Comment: @paulster2 such as a top cylinder lubricant?

Comment: No. This would go into the oil which would clean out the oil passages. Something like BG 109 EPR. (PS: Please notice my username is not lower cased. I didn't receive the above ping from you. Easiest way is to copy/paste it, placing it after the "@" symbol. Exclude the Mod diamond.)